# Change Infinite Scroll Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm using Infinite Scroll and Twitter style trigger to load posts. When I click on toggle it stays on it's place and Infinite Scrolls `#infscr-loading` appears above it. I would want to make it so that custom triggers value changes to "loading more posts" or something like that, and #infscr-loading doesn't appear above it. After loading new posts it should revert back to "load more posts" trigger and when there's no more posts to load, it would say "all posts loaded". I hope you understood my point. Here's result I want: http://jscroll.com/ on demo 2.

JS

```
$(function() {

    var $container = $('.posts');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.post',
            isFitWidth: true,
            "gutter": 30
        });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: '.infinite-pagination .load-more-posts',
            nextSelector: '.infinite-pagination .load-more-posts',
            itemSelector: '.post',
            behavior: 'twitter',
            loading: {
                img: 'http://static.tumblr.com/hpghjri/FA5n90quf/loading.gif',
                msgText: 'Loading more posts',
                finishedMsg: 'All posts loaded'
            }
        },
        // trigger Masonry as a callback
        function(newElements) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function() {
                // show elems now they're ready
                $newElems.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
                $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
            });
        }
    );
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="infinite-pagination">
    <a class="load-more-posts" href="{NextPage}">Load more posts</a>
</div>
```

Live Preview

http://primor-demo.tumblr.com

Comment: The language of your post is a little confusing, I believe what you want to do is configure `msgText` to be 'loading more posts' and `finishedMsg` to be 'all posts loaded'

Comment: @Ben Sorry about that. I updated question. Here's result I want: http://jscroll.com/ on demo 2, but it needs to be implemented with Infinite Scroll plugin.